# PowerShell 5.1 What's the difference between inline function and all the other ones?

Tags: azure, powershell, vscode-snippets

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 and I'm using inline functions just fine in my script. But I can't find anything online telling me why I wouldn't use inline functions. My main context is using Azure pipeline tasks to call my PowerShell scripts.

[image]

Comment: Those appear to be names of code snippets. What does it insert if you go for the `function-inline` snippet? "Inline function" is not a concept within PowerShell itself, as far as I know ("advanced function" is), but of course people are free to name their snippets whatever they like.

Comment: doh! it actually explains a little about it if you hover over it in VSCode

Answer (score 4):

`function-inline` is a snippet for a function where the parameters are defined inline with the function name rather than in a parameter block.

The `function-inline` creates:

```
function FunctionName (OptionalParameters) {
    
}
```

Whereas a `function` is:

```
function FunctionName {
    param (
        OptionalParameters
    )
    
}
```

The different location of `OptionalParameters` is the only difference.

IMX, parameter blocks are typically preferred for all but the most trivial of functions.

Comment: Nicely done, but what does _IMX_ mean?

Answer (score 3):

[Bacon Bits helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72307941/7571258) already shows the basic syntactic difference.

A major difference is that you can't use the [`CmdletBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute) attribute with *inline* functions.

Somewhat surprisingly, you can write [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) as both *inline* and non-inline functions:

```sh
# Advanced function using inline syntax:
function InlineFun( [Parameter()] $a ) { 
    $PSCmdlet 
}

# Advanced function using non-inline syntax:
function Fun {
    param( [Parameter()] $a ) 
    $PSCmdlet 
}
```

A function becomes an *advanced* one if it either has `CmdletBinding()` or at least one `Parameter()` attribute. As proof the functions output the automatic `$PSCmdlet` variable, which is only available to advanced functions.

One case where you actually need the `param()` block is when you want to write a **parameter-less advanced function**:

```sh
function Fun {
    [CmdletBinding()] param() 
    $PSCmdlet 
}
```

In this case you need to use the `CmdletBinding()` attribute, which can't be used with an inline function because it is an attribute of the `param()` block.